# Exception when executing agent aggregation/aggregator

Tags: installation

I'm getting the following error when I try to install packages in my local Sitecore 9.0.1 installation.  I suspect it may have something to do with the certificate (as stated in the error) but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I've double checked the thumbprint in my config and compared to the certs on SSL. I even shut off SSL both on IIS for the site and in my app.config to no avail.

```
14832 15:17:57 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/aggregator
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.AsyncPoolScheduler`2..ctor(IAsyncProcessingPool`1 pool, IXdbContextFactory xdbContextFactory, ExpandOptions options, Int16 maxBatchSize)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.InteractionAggregationAgent.<ExecuteCoreAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.Agent.<ExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.<ExecuteAgentAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.<RunAsync>d__26.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: The certificate was not found.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifier.Process(HttpClientHandler handler)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.CreateRequestHandler()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.CreateClient()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteGetAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient.<Refresh>d__4.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember that I had a similar kind of thing and after lots of research I found the solution by removing the unused `SC certificates` from your `current user certificate stores`. Maybe for some reason, you have it there. This may happen that you have accidentally installed some certs in your `Current User store` instead of the `Local Computer store`.

This may also happen that there are an old set of certificates from a previous install which meant their thumbprint didn't match with current install.

So it looks like any certs you have in your `Current User store` will override any certs you have in your Local Computer, So verify and check by deleting the old certs then restart `IIS` and then verify that it should work.